# To get class of closest ddl1(dropdownlist 1) on ddl2 selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below sample code shows a div (a table cell) which contains two child div's. 1st child div contains ddl1 and 2nd child div contains ddl2.

When I select ddl2, I need to get class `c-drpdwn-grade" + i + "" + j + "` of ddl1. Suppose if `i=0` and `j=1`, class name will be `c-drpdwn-grade01`. As the main div is a table cells, need to get class of closest ddl1  of the selected dropdown on the 2nd div(ddl2).

```
$('.innerdiv' + i).append(
"<div class='d-flex border-btm job-dtls-clm'>\
    <div class='d-flex-lft c-drpdwn-no-block'>\
        <select id='user_grade' class='c-drpdwn-grade c-drpdwn-grade" + i + "" + j + "'></select>\
    </div>\
    <div class='d-flex-rgt c-drpdwn-block'>\
        <select id='resources_dropdown' class='c-drpdwn-resrs-new c-drpdwn-resrs"+ i + "" + j + "' data-select-search='true'>\
            <option></option>\
        </select>\
    </div>\
</div>");
```

Dropdown change code:

```
.on("select2:select", function (e) {
    console.log($(this).closest('#user_grade'));        
    //$(this).closest('#user_grade').val(1).trigger('change');
    //$('.c-drpdwn-grade01').val(1).trigger('change')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest just parent div `.job-dtls-clm` which holds both select and then find first select inside it

```
.on("select2:select", function (e) {
    console.log($(this).closest('.job-dtls-clm')).find('select:nth-child(1)')
});
```

Another way, you can set `j` and `i` as data attribute in select. With this attribute data you can easly find classname

```
    <select data-ij = "+ i + "" + j + "'>\
        <option></option>\
    </select>\

    .on("select2:select", function (e) {
        var dataIj = $(this).attr('data-ij')
        console.log('c-drpdwn-grade' + dataIj) //searched class name          

    });
```